# White Screen Appears When Installing Sign Apk in Samsung S8

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I have created a Sign APK going through .Droid -> Archive,
Which is Installing in all the Devices of android without any problem
but in Samsung S8 White Screen Appears & nothing happens.
Dev build is also installing successfully on Samsung S8 but Sign APK
Has Issue.
I have done Clean & Build many Times but nothing worked for me.

Comment: What are you using in your splash activity or after splash activity?

Comment: What is reported in `logcat`?

Comment: [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name",MainLauncher = true)]

Comment: Can you please expose us the error log or your snippet so that it would be easy to answer to report your question. Meanwhile, what I suggest you is to enable debug library such as fabric and see where exactly are you facing an issue. Please refer this link https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/advanced-settings/debugging.html